# How to prove a drive isn't in use?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, hard-drive, hardware

I have a drive that I'm working to replace. I believe it's no longer in use by any system or user and that it can be removed. I've copied everything off of it that I think is relevant.

Is there a way to prove that the drive isn't in use any more?

Ideas:

- Examine a hash of the entire drive's contents now and compare it in a week?
- Log any access to the drive using lsof or some other kernel-level feature?
- Get the last read or write information from the SMART utils on the drive?

Any other ideas? Ideally I'd like to monitor it for a week or so, just to be sure. If any data is read or written during that time, I'd like to know that fact.

Seems like a simple concept, but I haven't been able to find any good results for this.

**UPDATE** - The filesystem is ext4.

Comment: Un-mount the filesystem, and wait for shouting?  The advantage being that you can have it offline, but be easy to re-enable?

Comment: Does `lsof` work for you in this case for monitoring?

Comment: @Zoredache I think that must be the standard practice, but....this feels like something a computer can do better.

Comment: Well the more useful answer would probably depend on what exactly this drive was being used for in the first place.  What services were storing data on it, and so on.  Monitor those services.  Without **more specific details** about how it was being used, what filesystem was on it, or so on, I am not sure anyone will be able to suggest anything that can be applied universally.

Comment: Have you tried `udiskctl power-off -b /dev/sdn`? (where `sdn` would be the appropriate device file, of course). Its man page states:
`Arranges for the drive to be safely removed and powered off. On the OS side this includes ensuring that no process is using the drive, then requesting that in-flight buffers and caches are committed to stable storage. The exact steps for powering off the drive depends on the drive itself and the interconnect used. `

Comment: @Zoredache Thought about the same.

Comment: @Zoredache the idea here is that the method ought to work regardless of the way the disk is being used, but can we just assume it's being used by 100 monkeys that were supposed to stop using it last week? I've updated the post with the filesystem.

Comment: @mlissner I really don't think there is any truly generic method, that would be foolproof.  That said, I have voted to re-open.  I am always up to learn something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat /proc/diskstats`.  Take note of the values for the device you wish to remove.  Wait a period of time.  `cat /proc/diskstats` again.  If the first or fifth numbers after the device name have gone up, something has read (first number) or written (fifth number) from/to the disk over the time period at hand.

[`Documentation/iostats.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt) has all the gory details about `/proc/diskstats` and what all the numbers mean, if you're into that kind of thing.

Comment: This is wonderful! Thanks for hopping in here to show that I wasn't crazy!